# C# - Placing a PDF inside another PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, watermark

I have multiple logos of various companies in various formats that needs to be added to other PDFs. The format of these logos is not specified at the moment but it could be locked down to only certain formats if it causes issues.

These other PDFs will be mostly posters and will be printed off by the user.

Question: What is the best way for adding these logo's onto the PDF poster artwork on the fly to then be downloaded and printed by the user? Bareing in mind it needs to retain the original quality of the PDF when being printed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See at my answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204860/best-server-side-net-pdf-editing-library). In short, I've used [itextsharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/) to add watermark(s) to an existing PDF.

Answer (score 1):

[PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/) is a free library that can do this.  [These watermarking examples](http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=40&Itemid=51) should help you get started.