# Libraries to Quickly Create Pdfs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I want to take a list of objects and create that into a table and display that into a pdf file. Is there any good libraries out there that I can use?

```
MyObject a = new MyObject();
a.Name = "bob";
a.Address = "123 fake st";

pdf output

Name    Address
bob    123 fake st
jim     test
```

I looked at pdfsharp/migradoc but it does not seem to work on medium trust so I am not sure if it will work on my shared hosting.

I heard of itextsharp but did not really look into it as they seemed to have changed their licensing and the new licensing forces you to make your project open I believe.

Comment: are you only interested in free libraries? I would use DevExpress XtraReports, worth every single penny, especially the DXperience subscriptions, with plenty of components for all platforms including MVC, WPF, SL, Winforms and ASP.NET classic. I made my company to acquire 14 licenses recently and we are all very satisfied.

Comment: Yes free libraries only as this is just for a personal site and I really don't want to spend money on libraries for it.

Comment: You are using C#, asp.net. Are you using SQLServer too? It has some CLR libraries that can do this. Sounds wierd, I know, but I have been using for years. If you have SQLServer you MAY have already paid for those libraries.

Comment: I do have a database under my plan. I don't know if I get access to this feature though. If it is something that you need rights too then probably not. I also was looking for something in memory as I first generate everything in memory and might as well use that if I can.

Comment: I have used iText for personal use. Looked good to me. `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204860/best-server-side-net-pdf-editing-library`

Comment: They changed their licensing agreement. So now you have to buy a license or basically make your project open source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use iTextsharp. And here's a nice [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC3) which illustrates how Razor views could directly be exported to PDF using iTextsharp and the RazorEngine package.

Comment: Be aware of the iText license details: http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php

Comment: Ya. I would use it but I don't want to open my whole site up just to use it.